# What am I doing wrong with my references?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, apacite

I am training myself in the use of Latex using Texworks but I don't understand why I keep getting errors when I try to link a reference. They are Re**search.tex 9
LaTeX Warning: Citation `shad2014' undefined on input line 9.** and **Research.tex LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references**.
I don't know why they keep popping up and the end result keeps showing? (?)

How can I fix this? my intention was to have a footer containing the reference. I need it to be in APA for university and at the end of the documents, I need the bibliography printed as well. I don't understand the documentation well enough to work it out myself.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{apacite} 
\begin{document}
\title{Research}
\author{Newbie}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction} 
aaa ~\citeA {shad2014} 
\bibliographystyle{apacite}   
\bibliography{Fonterra References} 
\end {document}
```

Here is the .bib document with the reference

```
@article{shad2014,   
   title={Fonterra as a case study of co-operative capital structure innovation},   
   author={Shadbolt, NM and Duncan, Alex},   
   journal={International Summit of Cooperatives, Quebec, Canada},   
   pages={6--9},  
   year={2014}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome! Remove the space fro `Fonterra References` i.e. use `FonterraReferences` and `FonterraReferences.bib`. Avoid weird characters in file names - they spell trouble. Then run pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex to see your bibliography.

Comment: Any chance you could have better line breaks (narrower lines)?

Comment: Did you run BibTeX after running LaTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to making sure that the filename of the bib file is parsable, do make sure that you're using the correct entry type for the entry at hand. It doesn't look like `@article` is the correct entry type; use either `@misc` or `@inproceedings`. And, be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more each time you add or delete `\cite`-type directives in the body of the document.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{shad2014,   
   title={Fonterra as a Case Study of Cooperative Capital Structure Innovation},   
   author={Shadbolt, Nicola M. and Duncan, Alex},   
   howpublished={Paper presented at Qu{\'e}bec 2014 International Summit of Cooperatives},  
   year={2014}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{apacite} 
\bibliographystyle{apacite}   

\begin{document}
\citeA{shad2014} argue that \dots
\bibliography{mybib} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: To me, personally, this is the very same answer given so  many times on TeX.SX. The overall question (probably) would be a duplicate. The rest would be too localized, not helpful for others -> off-topic.

Comment: @Johannes_B - It's depressingly common, in queries posted to this site, to see entry types such as `@article` be overused (and abused!) as some sort of catch-all entry type. That's why I bothered to post a longer answer. I do fully agree with you that the recommendation to run LaTeX/BibTeX/LaTeX/LaTeX must be one of the most common dupes on this site...